# How to interpret training results

Tags: keras, image-classification, overfitting, python-3.x

I am working on an image similarity network. I have around 90,000 pairs of images contain an equal number of positive and negative samples. For learning the similarity between image pairs, I used the pre-trained network (VGGNet-16). After getting feature vectors I merged them and use their merged feature vectors as an input to the similarity network. 
The similarity network contains two convolution layers and four fully connected layers. I trained the network and only after first epoch I got the following outcome:

```
    Epoch 1/1
    1382/1382 [=======] - 1557s 1s/step - loss: 0.3431 - acc: 0.9556 - val_loss: 0.3334 - val_acc: 0.9874
```

I am a newbie in neural networks. Could someone comment on this result after a single epoch? I saw networks require 100’s of epochs to achieve accuracy up to 95%. Is this overfitting? Looking for suggestions.

Comment: This could be due to over-fitting, you can use regularization techniques. One of the most common is dropout.

Comment: It is difficult to say from just the training loss and accuracy whether or not the network is overfitting. Try using a validation dataset and compare the validation metrics with the training metrics so you can better evaluate if the network if overfitting.

Comment: @Oxbowerce the outputs were not complete. I mistakenly removed the validation part. For the validation dataset, I reserved 11500 image pairs and use them during training. Now could you please have a look above in the output section. There is validation accuracy and loss. They are almost equal.

Comment: @AKASHSINDHU is there any golden rule to apply Dropout regularization? I mean I have in total six layers (2 convolution and four dense layers) do I need to use dropout after each layer or to some specific? What about the rate of the dropout? Any suggestions or any good article/blog which can help me.

Comment: @AliRazaMemon since the the validation accuracy is still higher than the training accuracy I would not say the network is overfitting. I think you can try training for more epochs and what validation accuracy you can achieve before overfitting.